# Access a remote class via my file system in Java

Tags: java, class

I want to access a 'remote' class using paths.  My file system is:
....\Java\ResourceDW\MyRectangle.java

....\Java\Workspace\W09-ClassHeader\src\W09ClassHeader.java

I'm trying to access MyRectangle.java from W09ClassHeader.java

in C++ I can do: #include "./../../../ResourceDW/ClassMySphere.dw"

Can I do something similar without using 'com'  I'm just local.

Thanks, David W.

Comment: You can do that by using `-cp` in `java` and `javac` command. Try something like this  `java -cp ".;./../../../ResourceDW/ClassMySphere.dw"`

Comment: Nothing remotely remote about this. You're just talking about a class in a different file system location.

Comment: Yes the java -cp sounds great, but I was not specific enough.  I am using the Eclipse IDE, and as far as I understand it the 'java' command only works on the command line..  I get the other comment about remote (bad terminology), what I meant was in another directory, Thanks.